# Modifying Security Group from ElasticBeanstalk extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

I'm trying to make EB add `HTTPS` (port 443) to my security group when I run `eb deploy`.

Currently I have this:

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Which is exactly what [AWS's EB doc suggest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-tomcat.html). But for some reason it's not working. When I run `eb deploy`, the security group attached to my instance doesn't change (the `443` port isn't added).

Why it isn't working? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS documentation you've followed is for EC2 instances not running with Beanstalk.
I suggest you to add this lines to your .ebextensions files :

```
option_settings:
  aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    ListenerEnabled: 'true'
    Protocol: HTTPS
```